# HTTP if-none-match and if-modified-since and 304 clarification in PHP

Tags: php, http, caching, http-1.1

My question is about how to reply a HTTP 304 "Not Modified" when I receive **both** if-none-match and if-modified-since from a proxy/client request.

From RFC 2616 secttion 14.26 ( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26 ):

> If none of the entity tags match, then
>   the server MAY perform the requested
>   method as if the If-None-Match header
>   field did not exist, but MUST also
>   ignore any If-Modified-Since header
>   field(s) in the request. That is, if
>   no entity tags match, then the server
>   MUST NOT return a 304 (Not Modified)
>   response.

I am not sure to understand this statement...

1. "If none of the entity tags match" in PHP do they speak of `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` vs. my ETags that I sent earlier?
2. If I understand correctly this statement, as soon as none of the ETags listed in `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` match my ETags, I stop all verifications and serve the page normally.

Anyone can translate this RFC part in pseudo-code (or PHP code) and/or answer my 2 points above?

**EDIT 1:**
Thank you St.Woland for your answer. Can you (or anyone else) tell me if I'm correct on these 6 points:

1. The format of `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` can be either:

   a)If-None-Match: "xyzzy", "r2d2xxxx", "c3piozzzz"

   b) If-None-Match: "xyzzy"

   **and NOT:**

   c) If-None-Match: "xyzzy, r2d2xxxx, c3piozzzz"
2. If `!array_key_exists('HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH', $_SERVER)`, anyTagMatched() returns NULL.
3. As soon as an ETag in `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` match my document ETag, anyTagMatched() returns TRUE.
4. If none of the Etags in `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']` are matching my document ETag, `anyTagMatched()` returns FALSE.
5. If `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` is set and matches my document "last modified" date `isExpired()` returns FALSE, otherwise return TRUE.
6. As soon as `anyTagMatched()` returns TRUE, I issue a 304. If anyTagMatched() returned NULL and `isExpired()` returned FALSE I can issue a 304. In any other situation I serve my page as normal (I also issue the up-to-date Last-Modified and ETag headers).

Comment: Take a look at:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000715/answering-httpifmodifiedsince-and-httpifnonematch-in-php
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583740/304-not-modified-and-front-end-caching

Comment: As per definition, an unquoted value is invalid (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.11).

Comment: Great to know, I should learn to read those field definitions in RFCs! Point "1-C" is still invalid right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be put in the end (moved for better look).

```
$anyTagMatched = anyTagMatched() ;
if( $anyTagMatched || ( ( null === $anyTagMatched ) && !isExpired() ) ) {
    notModified() ;
}
// Output content
```

Pseudocode (review needed):

```
<?php

/**
 * Calculates eTag for the current resource.
 */
function calculateTag() {
}

/**
 * Gets date of the most recent change.
 */
function lastChanged() {
}

/**
 * TRUE if any tag matched
 * FALSE if none matched
 * NULL if header is not specified
 */
function anyTagMatched() {
    $if_none_match = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) ?
        stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) : 
        false ;

    if( false !== $if_none_match ) {
        $tags = split( ", ", $if_none_match ) ;
        $myTag = calculateTag() ;
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
            if( $tag == $myTag ) return true ;
        }
        return false ;
    }
    return null ;
}

function isExpired() {
    $if_modified_since = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) ?
        stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) :
        false;

    if( false !== $if_modified_since ) {
        // Compare time here; pseudocode.
        return ( $if_modified_since < lastChanged() ) ;
    }

    return true ;
}

function notModified() {
    header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
    exit ;
}
```

Main answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021882/is-my-implementation-of-http-conditional-get-answers-in-php-is-ok/2049723#2049723).

Comment: In your isExpired() function what if $if_modified_since == false? The function don't return anything...

Comment: It should obviously return `true`, as IF-MODIFIED-SINCE header isn't set. I've changed the code accordingly. Sorry for that, it really needs a deeper examination, but that's what you were asking for: pseudocode.

Comment: Added "EDIT 1" in question. It would be great if you have time to confirm my points. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this! May I ask where all this knowledge comes from?

Comment: If you could look look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111854/what-does-the-http-header-if-none-match-means I still don't understand the * in If-None-Match means :)

Comment: The PHP function `split` is deprecated. You can use `explode` instead.