# HTTP If-None-Match vs. If-Match

Tags: http, caching, header, http-headers, http-1.1

I'm currently building up a PHP script that will answer HTTP "304 Not Modified" when required.

(See [question #2086712](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086712/http-if-none-match-and-if-modified-since-and-304-clarification-in-php) for what I do so far).

Currently I answer to the following:

- If-Modified-Since
- If-None-Match

But I found out that 3 more headers can trigger a "conditional GET" (See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3):

- If-Match
- If-Unmodified-Since
- If-Range

The last 2 seems irrevelent to my caching system (they seem to be used when resuming "big" downloads) but I haven't found if "If-Match" could be of use in my system.

Does "If-Match" is used in proxies or Web browser for "regular" page content? How "If-Match" is different than "If-None-Match"?

Should I support those 3 or just some of them? Any help welcome!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## If-Match

The server MUST return a 412 (Precondition Failed) response, if:

- none of the entity tags match,
- or "*" is given and no current entity exists

If-Match should be ignored, if:

- any of the entity tags match
- or if the request results in anything other than a 2xx or 412 status (without If-Match)
- or if "*" is given and any current entity exists for the resource

Conclusion on **if-match**:

- The meaning of "If-Match: *" is that the method should be performed if the representation selected by the origin server ... exists, and must not be performed if the representation does not exist.

[If-Match in RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24)

## If-Unmodified-Since

The server MUST return a 412 (Precondition Failed) response, if:

- the requested variant has been modified since the specified time

If-Unmodified-Since should be ignored, if

- the requested resource has not been modified since the time specified in this field
- or the request normally (i.e., without the If-Unmodified-Since header) would result in anything other than a 2xx or 412 status
- or the specified date is invalid

[If-Unmodified-Since in RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.28)

## If-Range

> Informally, its meaning is 'if the entity is unchanged, send me the part(s) that I am missing; otherwise, send me the entire new entity'

Preconditions:

- The `If-Range` header **SHOULD** only be used together with a `Range` header, and **MUST** be ignored if the request ***does not include*** a `Range` header, or if the server ***does not support*** the sub-range operation.

Server SHOULD provide 206 (Partial content) response, if `If-Range` header matches the current entity tag for the entity. Otherwise, server SHOULD return the entire entity using a 200 (OK) response.

[If-Range in RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.27)

## Undefined results

Having the following combination of headers leads to an undefined result:

- If-Modified-Since **and** If-Match
- If-Modified-Since **and** If-Unmodified-Since
- If-None-Match **and** If-Match
- If-None-Match **and** If-Unmodified-Since

These rules have been decomposed from the following ones (can be found in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)):

- If-Match **and** ( If-None-Match **or** If-Modified-Since )
- If-Modified-Since **and** ( If-Match **or** If-Unmodified-Since )
- If-None-Match **and** ( If-Match **or** If-Unmodified-Since )
- If-Unmodified-Since **and** ( If-None-Match **or** If-Modified-Since )

A more recent [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) superseded 2616.

Comment: Is there situation where If-Match, If-Unmodified-Since or If-Range can trigger a HTTP 304 "Not Modified" answer?

Comment: No, it's only allowed for `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers

Comment: Isn't that `If-Match: *` conflicts with 404?

Comment: Answering my own question, If-Match has a condition that make itself the last resolve chain, therefore 404 normally takes precedence.

Comment: still what is the difference between if-none-match and if-match? How should the two case be handled differently? or is one just negating the other?