# Codeigniter default controller displays Blank Page

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-304

Why I am getting Blank Page for my default controller, It was working fine, suddenly started this behaviour, I dont know what I did wrong, I am searching for a solution, no luck so far, Using chrome tool I get this, please see the image below

[image]

My default controller is Home.php, If I use http://dreamsonlinepress.dev/home, I can access controller, I get result. I tested with creating testing controller with no code, just echoing some text, same result.

In the routes.php file I haven't changed anything so far to get this 304 status.
Any Idea will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like caching. [In a comment in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1583753/3585500), you can force Chrome to reload the page with Shift-Reload.

Comment: I have tried those all steps, no luck so far

Comment: have you specified your default controller as home in route ? for eg $route['default_controller'] = "home";

Comment: @AmitChauhan Yes Brother, I Have tried to change that with some other controllers also, like About, etc...